# Java - Scanner Class - Skipping over the first line when reading a textfile

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

When using a Scanner object to read from a textfile, I want it to skip over the very first line in the file. How would I do achieve this?

Comment: Just make a call of nextLine before you start reading anything. You don't have to assign the output anywhere, just call file.nextLine() sometime before you begin reading the data you want. Just make sure there's at least ONE line or you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `file.nextLine()` before your while loop. This will skip the first line, as explained  in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29).

And a note about your naming. The Java language has widely accepted conventions. Class Names always start with an upper case letter, and variable names always start with a lower case  letter (except constants, but don't worry about that now). Read more [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: Had to give a -1 just because of the inaccurate information supplied regarding Java naming conventions.

Comment: Would you elaborate on that please? How was it inaccurate? I even linked the original document. I just intended to point the OP in the right direction, since his naming was off.

Comment: Class names are not in upperCase, they are in UpperCase. Variable names are not all in lowercase, they are in camelCase.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, that was quick writing. To be exact, both are in camelCase. What I meant to say was, that class names start with an upper case letter and variable names start with a lower case letter. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code before the `while` loop to skip the first line.

```
if(file.hasNext()==true)
{
   file.nextLine();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Error: File is empty");
    return null;
}
```